# Kubernetes Deployment with StorageClass

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have a `StorageClass` with `provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs`

And I have a deployment where I need to mount some volumes. So, I need to use this `StorageClass`

Here's my `sc.yaml`

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: gp2
parameters:
  fsType: ext4
  type: gp2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Here's my `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: var.namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.4
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      # how can I specify my storage class here?
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

I need to specify the storage class in my deployment. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to specify the storage class in my deployment. Can someone help me?

Before we answer, first let's explain how `StroageClass`, `PersistentVolume`, `Persistent Volume Claim`.

#### Terminology

##### `StroageClass`

- We can look at `StorageClass` as a driver (Software).
- A driver which responsible for the "communication" with the storage hardware.
- Usually but not a must, the `StorageClass` is supplied by the Storage provider (hardware or virtual)

##### `PersistentVolume`

- A `PersistentVolume` (PV) is a **piece of storage** in the cluster **that has been provisioned** by an administrator or dynamically provisioned using `Storage Classes`.

##### `PersistentVolumeClaim`

- A `PersistentVolumeClaim` (PVC) is a **request for storage** by a user (Usually Pod)

---

#### General Diagram (describing K8 Storage objects)

[image: K8 Storage Diagram]

### TL;DR; Explanation

- You have physical storage (Disk, SSD, virtual, etc)
- Someone (usually the storage or the cloud provider) supplied you with the `StorageClass` object. By the way, you don't need to define/declare it most of the time and K8S will supply default storage for you ([emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir)).
- Then you define `PersistentVolume` (PV) which will "create" storage based upon the type (`StorageClass`) you require.
- Next step is to define `PersistentVolumeClaim` (PVC). The PVC is the allocation of the "physical" storage mounted from the (PV) which you defined in the previous step.
- The last step is to "assign" volume to your execution (`Pod`, `Deployment`, `StatefulSet`, etc) which is done using `volumes`.

** Notes

- As mentioned above most of the time you can simply use volumes without the need to define `StorageClass` or `PV`/`PVC`. Simply use a volume in the required  Resources and K8S will take care of that for you.
- There are some exceptions (without getting into too many details here like `StaefulSet`).
  If no StorageClass is specified, then the default StorageClass will be used

---

Now let's answer your question

- You have defined a `StorageClass`

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
...
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
```

- In your deployment, you specified `volumes` (identation left as as)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
...
        
        # --> Here you define the actual mount path you need for your pods
        #     The name (PVC) is corresponding to the one you 
        #     defined below under volumes
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      # ->>>> how can I specify my storage class here?
      # You don't need to specify storage class, you need to define PVC,
      # This is the missing piece in your code.
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

#### The missing piece ...

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim ### <<< The name as mentioned above in your Deploymnet
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  # The name of the storage class u defined earlier
  storageClassName: gp2

  # The access modes are:
  #   ReadWriteOnce - The volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
  #   ReadWriteMany - The volume can be mounted as read-write by a many nodes
  #   ReadOnlyMany  - The volume can be mounted as read-only  by many nodes
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

---

Hope it helped you out.

Comment: Thank you so much for you explanation CodeWizard. But PVC keeps creating forever. I am using `terraform` to provision these resources.

Comment: This is another issue..... :-)

Comment: Thanks man. Fixed the issue with `wait_until_bound = false`

Comment: Cool, glad to help :-)